# Как проверить, что radiobutton выбран?

Tags: delphi

Как написать, что радиокнопка активна?

if radiobutton4 ...? then

Comment: @Vinsent75, старайтесь писать название вопроса соответствующее его содержанию.

Answer (score 3):

Используется свойство **Checked**.

true - активна, false пассивна

Answer (score 0):

```
if radiobutton4.checked then
begin
  ShowMessage('Радиокнопка активна');
end
else
begin
  ShowMessage('Радиокнопка не активна');
end
```

Comment: всем дельфы, посаны

Comment: @niki-timofe, поправьте ответ. ТС не сможет определить, что это ``c`` и перевести в ``pascal``.

Comment: @Yuri Ivanov если вы про меня, то я просто так написал. Просто судя по вопросам я не удивлюсь если они (авторы) такое перепишут в код и удивятся, что не работает

Comment: Перевёл в `pascal`

Comment: `if radiobutton1.checked = true <> false = (2 * 2 = 4) then`

Comment: @karmadro4 Это на всякий случай

Comment: На какой "всякий"? В военное время значение синуса может достигать четырех? :-)